# storing object in array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a simple tower defense game.
I have a tower which detects an enemy and starts shooting at it.
But for now everything is very simple, and I want to modify it. 
The tower has an array of objects, and if a new enemy steps in, it should be the first object in the array. So what is the best way of doing it ?

Comment: Well what have you tried, and what went wrong? At the moment your question is very unclear.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a queue? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

Comment: @L-Three I wouldn't use queues for this since he's talking about enemies in a game. There is a high chance that enemies die while in the middle of the "array" and then need to be removed.

Comment: I think it should be not queue (first-in-first-out) but a stack (last-in-first-out)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use lists instead of arrays. They provide much more functionality like Add, insert, Remove,... and are dynamic so they can grow in size if more enemies appear in your game.